# Python: Conditional 'if' statement to set rate

Tags: python

I'm making a game where the user must shoot an incoming wave of enemies.

I am trying to increase the speed of the rate at which the enemies spawn by checking the current score. However I keep getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
 for x in range(score):

     if score is > 5 and < 10:
           spawnrate = 6
     elif score is > 10 and < 20:
           spawnrate = 8
     elif score is > 20:
           spawnrate = 10
```

Comment: what error ? do you get error message - then add full text.

Comment: And why you use `for` loop ?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if `score` is equal to 10 or 20?

Answer (score 2):

`is` is incorrect, and while it is possible to chain comparisons together, you are doing that incorrectly as well.

Use either

```
if 5 < score < 10:
```

or (more explicitly)

```
if 5 < score and score < 10:
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than testing each case for low and high values, you can let the `if`-cases cascade, like

```
if score < 5:
    spawnrate = 4
elif score < 10:
    spawnrate = 6
elif score < 20:
    spawnrate = 8
else:
    spawnrate = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `is` and you have to use variable twice with `and`

```
 if score > 5 and score < 10:
       spawnrate = 6
 elif score > 10 and score < 20:
       spawnrate = 8
 elif score > 20:
       spawnrate = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The line :

```
elif score > 10 and score < 20:
```

Should be :

```
elif score > 10 and score < 20:
```

In addition, python allows you to do something like this :

```
elif 10 < score < 20:
```